# Write a statement that will be true if A = $\Bbb Z$ and false if A = $\Bbb N$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Write a statement that will be true if A = $\Bbb Z$ and false if A = $\Bbb N$, using only quantifiers, logical connectives, variables, parentheses, equals sign and addition symbol. Any variable is assumed to be a member of A.

Here is what I have so far:

$\forall x\exists y \exists z((x+y=x) \land \exists z(x+z=y))$

However it seems that this is only valid if A contains only even numbers.

Comment: consider $\forall x\forall y\exists z (x=y+z)$. in $\mathbb{Z}$, just let $z=x-y$, but if $y>x$ such an element will not exist in $\mathbb{N}$

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom thanks for the tip but I'm not allowed to use - or >

Comment: the sentence "$\forall x\forall y\exists z(x=y+z)$" doesn't use those characters

Comment: the only place those characters were used is in the (informal) proof that this sentence holds in $\mathbb{Z}$ but not in $\mathbb{N}$, but that doesn't mean the sentence itself contains them. does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

If your definition of $\mathbb{N}$ does not contain $0$, then the formula could be
$$\exists x\,\, \forall y\,\,x+y=y.$$

Comment: N does contain 0 in this case, but someone else made an interesting point. The questions doesn't say the statement must be true ONLY when A = Z. So it seems I was over complicating the question

Comment: It is not possible to define $\mathbb{Z}$ by a statement like this.